# Mathematica: how can I model RC and get the R and C value from CSV

Tags: csv, wolfram-mathematica, response

I hope some one can help me.

I have a CSV file with voltage Response and current step values. I have to make a RC model in mathematica and find the R and C value.

How can I model the RC in mathematica und extract the Parameters from the values in CSV File?

I did this :

```
Data=Import["T:/file.csv","CSV"];
```

My Data have a header and 2 columns. a column for Current und column for voltage Response.

```
Voltage=data[[35;;,1]];Current=data[[35;;,2]];
```

My file have a header, thats why I write 35 to drop the header.
[image: Hier ist my Current step]
[image: Hier ist my Voltage Response]

So now I have an RC model with  Resistor parallel to Capacitor and serial to other Resistor
[image: My RC Model]

```
Z= Ri+Rt//Ct  --> complex Form (Ri+Rt/1+jwR2Ct)
```

my model in mathematica looks like :

```
OutputResponse[StateSpaceModel[TransferFunction[{{Ri+Rt+sRt}/{1+sRt}},s,SamplingPeriod->0.1,SystemsModelLabels->None]],current];
```

how to extract the Ri Rt und Ct from the Voltage Response to put them in my Transferfunction to get the same Voltage Response as it looks like on the picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb2Kk.jpg)

Comment: Can you upload your data somewhere and give a link?

Comment: You might get a better response at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question.
Is it as follows: You have this CSV data file containing a table of values for your variables `Ri`, `Rt` and `Ct` and you want to plug those into your formula?

If that is the case, you could first define a function

```
response[Ri_ , Rt_, Ct_] := OutputResponse[... (as above)
```

Then assume your `Data` is a table that has those values in columns 1, 2, and 3 (you might need to adopt this).

Then you could:

```
Map[Function[r, response[r[[1]], r[[2]], r[[3]]], Data]
```

To obtain a table with the results.